# Не корректное написание HTML тега

Tags: html, jstl

У меня не самый сложный вопрос, но к сожалению мои познания в HTML очень слабые. На данный момент я делаю проект, в котором мне нужно вывести информацию в столбец из моей базы данных, но они почему-то отображаются в строке. Теперь дисплей выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также прикрепляю код со своей страницы jsp:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 50px 0 0 0">
            <table border="1"
                   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                   style="font-size: small; line-height: 100px; border-color: #D1EEEE">
                <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
                    <th width="250px">Discipline</th>
                    <th width="100px">Mark</th>
                </tr>


                    <c:forEach items="${Disc}" var="Dis">
                <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">${Dis.discipline}</td>
                        <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">0</td>
                </c:forEach>
                <td/>
            </table>
```

Прошу не пугаться такого ужасного написания, html не моя сильная сторона... заранее спасибо за понимание и буду очень благодарен за любую помощь в решении этого вопроса!

Comment: ты выводишь в цикле td'шки, но при этом для них нет ни одно tr'ки

Comment: `<td/>` - а это странная вещь...видимо не там слэш

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , эта очевидная ошибка исправлена и все работает как надо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из очевидного: Добавить <tr> и </tr> в цикл. Убрать непонятный <td/>.

```html
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 50px 0 0 0">
                            <table border="1"
                                   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"
                                   style="font-size: small; line-height: 100px; border-color: #D1EEEE">
                                <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #838B83">
                                    <th width="250px">Discipline</th>
                                    <th width="100px">Mark</th>
                                </tr>


                                    <c:forEach items="${Disc}" var="Dis">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">${Dis.discipline}</td>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom: 20px">0</td>
                                </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                                
                            </table>
```

Comment: Спасибо , ответ принимаю. Он решил мою проблему !